# How to execute Asynchronous Tasks Sequentially inside Synchronous Functions using React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, concurrency

**Problem:**

I am trying to execute a series of functions in a specific order. These functions all have asynchronous tasks inside of them; however, these functions need to happen sequentially.

The below code needs to do the following:

1. Delete current contents of Document Directory (this is because all files are persistent but I do NOT need them for permanent storage, only temporary)
2. Copy current file assets from their locations to the Document Directory
3. Zip up the folder of the Document Directory so I can store the zipped folder in AWS

Is it possible to ensure these functions wait for their asynchronous tasks to finish? (Some of these asynchronous tasks are run in a `forEach` loop -- this is not a single task within each function).

To take this a step further, can I execute the two (x2) `copyFilesToDocumentDirectory()` concurrently and still wait before executing `zipDocumentDirectory()`?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { zip } from 'react-native-zip-archive';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

export default class AddMedia extends React.Component {
    
    state = { 
        photoAssets: [], 
        videoAssets: [], 
        videoThumbnails: [],
        thumbnailReady: false
    };

    zipDocumentDirectory() {
        var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;
        console.log("Zipped");
        zip(path, path + "/urls.zip")
        .then((path) => {
            console.log("Zip complete");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };

    deleteContentsOfDocumentDirectory() {
        var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;
        var data = RNFS.readDir(path)
        .then((results) => {
            results.forEach(result => {
                /* I assume each item here is a FILE */
                RNFS.unlink(result.path)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("File Deleted");
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err.message);
                });
            });
        });
    };

    copyFilesToDocumentDirectory(assets) {
        var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;
        assets.forEach(asset => {
            RNFS.exists(asset.uri)
            .then((status) => {
                if(status) {
                    var newPath = path + "/" + asset.fileName;;
                    console.log("Copying from: ", asset.uri, " -- to: ", newPath);
                    RNFS.copyFile(asset.uri, newPath);
                };
            });
        });
    };
    
    storeToAWS() 
        this.deleteContentsOfDocumentDirectory();
        this.copyFilesToDocumentDirectory(this.state.photoAssets);
        this.copyFilesToDocumentDirectory(this.state.videoAssets);

        this.zipDocumentDirectory();
    
    };

    // ... Render code etc;
};
```

**Efforts:**

I wrote the above because that was the problem I am trying to solve. I thought this could be solved by `Promise`s but I am relatively new to the idea of promises/async/await. I tried adding `Promise`s to each method to wait for them to finish; however, the functions still ran synchronously and the asynchronous tasks ran after. The output is below the code showing the `Zipped` output inside `zipDocumentDirectory()` occurs BEFORE the asynchronous commands inside `copyFilesToDocumentDirectory()`.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { zip } from 'react-native-zip-archive';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

export default class AddMedia extends React.Component {
    
    state = { 
        photoAssets: [], 
        videoAssets: [], 
        videoThumbnails: [],
        thumbnailReady: false
    };

    zipDocumentDirectory() {
        var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;
        console.log("Zipped");
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            zip(path, path + "/urls.zip")
            .then((path) => {
                console.log("Zip complete");
                resolve();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                reject();
            });
        });
    };

    deleteContentsOfDocumentDirectory() {
        var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var data = RNFS.readDir(path)
            .then((results) => {
                results.forEach(result => {
                    /* I assume each item here is a FILE */
                    RNFS.unlink(result.path)
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log("File Deleted");
                        resolve();
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err.message);
                        reject();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    };

    copyFilesToDocumentDirectory(assets) {
        var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;
        assets.forEach(asset => {
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                RNFS.exists(asset.uri)
                .then((status) => {
                    if(status) {
                        var newPath = path + "/" + asset.fileName;;
                        console.log("Copying from: ", asset.uri, " -- to: ", newPath);
                        RNFS.copyFile(asset.uri, newPath);
                        resolve();
                    };
                });
            });
        });
    };
    
    storeToAWS = async () => {
        await this.deleteContentsOfDocumentDirectory();
        await this.copyFilesToDocumentDirectory(this.state.photoAssets);
        await this.copyFilesToDocumentDirectory(this.state.videoAssets);

        // 2. Zip temporary folder storage (with encryption)
        await this.zipDocumentDirectory();
```

```
OUTPUT:

 LOG  Zipped
 LOG  Copying from:  XYZ/FEB964FB-3ABB-4CF7-A3B0-1E90BD1932C4.jpg  -- to:  XYZ/FEB964FB-3ABB-4CF7-A3B0-1E90BD1932C4.jpg
```

Comment: You wrapped your functions with new promises but you never used `resolve`. The most important part is that you have to return the promise from the function, not only create it

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I added them (As well as edited the question) and it still runs synchronously without waiting for the asynchronous tasks to finish.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski You said return the promise from the function -- I see; I didn't do that here. How would I return multiple promises? i.e. my functions wrap these promises in a `forEach` iteration since I have to do it to each. If I were to return, only the first promise would return, no?

Comment: Change `forEach` to `map` and use `Promise.all`. You don't need to create a new promise when you already have a promise exposed like `RNFS.exists(asset.uri)`

Comment: Ahhhhh. I can just return the RNFS.exists -- I seeeee. Neat-o. Feel free to put it as an Answer and I'll make sure it all works out and give it the Good ole Green Check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added missing returns. I hope it will work now

````
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { zip } from 'react-native-zip-archive';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

export default class AddMedia extends React.Component {
    
    state = { 
        photoAssets: [], 
        videoAssets: [], 
        videoThumbnails: [],
        thumbnailReady: false
    };

    zipDocumentDirectory() {
        var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;
        console.log("Zipped");
        return zip(path, path + "/urls.zip")
        .then((path) => {
            console.log("Zip complete");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            reject();
        });
    };

    deleteContentsOfDocumentDirectory() {
        var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;
        return RNFS.readDir(path)
        .then((results) => {
            return Promise.all(results.map(result => {
                return RNFS.unlink(result.path)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("File Deleted");
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                     console.log(err.message);
                });
            }));
        });
    };

    copyFilesToDocumentDirectory(assets) {
        var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;
        return Promise.all(assets.map(asset => {
            return RNFS.exists(asset.uri)
                .then((status) => {
                    if(status) {
                        var newPath = path + "/" + asset.fileName;;
                        return RNFS.copyFile(asset.uri, newPath);
                    };
                });
            });
        }));
    };
    
    storeToAWS = async () => {
        await this.deleteContentsOfDocumentDirectory();
        await this.copyFilesToDocumentDirectory(this.state.photoAssets);
        await this.copyFilesToDocumentDirectory(this.state.videoAssets);

        // 2. Zip temporary folder storage (with encryption)
        await this.zipDocumentDirectory();
    }
}
    ```
````